# How to remove RuntimeError: Expected 2D (unbatched) or 3D (batched) input to conv1d, but got input of size: [96, 1, 28, 28]?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am running a simple 1d CNN model for MNIST dataset and doing it for research purpose so have to stick with using conv1d layer. My CNN model is as:

```
class net_mnist(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, output_size):
        super(net_mnist, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(1, 1, kernel_size=1, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=1, stride=2)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, 4096,bias = True)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(4096, 4096,bias = True)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(4096,4096,bias = True)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(4096,4096,bias = True)
        self.fc5 = nn.Linear(4096,output_size,bias = True)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x
        return x.squeeze()
```

And the function for loading dataset is:

```
transforms = Compose([
      ToTensor(),
    #     Normalize(
    #         mean=[0.1307],
    #         std=[0.3081],
    #     )
    ])
    trainset = MNIST(root = './mnist_data',train = True, download = True,transform=transforms)
    testset  = MNIST(root = './mnist_data',train = False,download = True,transform=transforms)

    trainloader = DataLoader(trainset,batch_size=96,shuffle=True)
    testloader  = DataLoader(testset ,batch_size=96,shuffle=True)
```

And cell where error is occuring is:

```
net = net_mnist(28*28, 10)
net.to(device)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss().to(device)
writer = SummaryWriter()
net = train_mnist(net,trainloader,testloader,criterion,lrate=0.03,max_epochs=6)
```

And following is the error:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-21-6bc9f6dcde7f> in <cell line: 5>()
      3 criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss().to(device)
      4 writer = SummaryWriter()
----> 5 net = train_mnist(net,trainloader,testloader,criterion,lrate=0.03,max_epochs=6)

5 frames
    /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in _conv_forward(self, input, weight, bias)
    307                             weight, bias, self.stride,
    308                             _single(0), self.dilation, self.groups)
--> 309         return F.conv1d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
    310                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    311 

    RuntimeError: Expected 2D (unbatched) or 3D (batched) input to conv1d, but got input of size: [96, 1, 28, 28]
```

I get it that to remove above error I need to flatten the images and then pass it as [96,1,784] vector but I can't understand how and where in the code I should do it to remove the error. I tried the solution given by Chatgpt but it didn't worked. And on internet I could not find the way to flatten the MNIST images for CNN structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just reshape the tensor.

```py
bs, c, h, w = image_tensor.shape
flattened_tensor = image_tensor.reshape(bs, c, h*w)
```

Also doing a 1d conv on a 1 channel input is kinda pointless. This is why most MNIST models just drop the channel and send the flattened input to a MLP.